# Zend Guard Run-time support missing even that ZendGuardLoader is linked properly

Tags: php, zend-framework, oxid

My OXID eShop displays this erorr:

> Zend Guard Run-time support missing! One more more files on this web
>   site were encoded by ZendGuard and the required run-time support is
>   not installed orproperly configured.

In my php.ini I have set the correct path to the ZendGuardLoader.so

phpinfo() says:

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend
>   Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
>
> ThreadSafety is disabled.

Could it be that the Apache Server has to be restarted? In this case should I contact my provider or is there a trick for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/products/guard) is not the same thing as the Zend Engine.

Contact your provider for help installing Zend Guard. Details will vary from host to host, so it's impossible for us to give a general solution here.